# Speed of increment number in TypeScript Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, time

So I have a function which is triggered on arrow down in Angular 4, when you hit the arrow down the counter is incremented by 1. Inside that function I need to run another function if a certain counter speed is matched.

```
 activeIndex = 0;

 if (event.code === "ArrowDown") { 
        this.activeIndex++ // 0.1.2.3...//incremented when you click arrow down, get the counter speed?

  if (this.activeIndex === "the speed??"){ 
     alert("function fired because the speed was...")
    }
```

Is there any way to count the speed of the counter++

Comment: Rxjs observables switchmap in multiple business logic functions/subjects should help. I think there is a throw ball game example in jsconf videos in you tube.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding what do you mean by "speed of increment++", and I'll assume you mean "the interval between each event call".

in that case, you can simply store the timestamp between each event call:

```
let lastKeyDownEvent = undefined;
const INTERVAL = 5000;

function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.code === "ArrowDown") {
        let currentKeyDownEvent = new Date().getTime();
        if (lastKeyDownEvent) {
            if ((currentKeyDownEvent - lastKeyDownEvent) < INTERVAL) {
                console.log('Events triggered in under ' + INTERVAL + ' milliseconds')
            } else {
                console.log('Events triggered in over ' + INTERVAL + ' milliseconds');
            }
        }
        lastKeyDownEvent = currentKeyDownEvent;
    }
}
```

You can, of course, include whatever other behavior you need within your keydown function.

Other way to approach this problem would be to use `setTimeout` to throttle your events:

```
let eventTimeout = undefined;
const INTERVAL = 5000;

function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.code === "ArrowDown") {
        if (eventTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(eventTimeout);
        }
        eventTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("No event has occured within " + INTERVAL + " milliseconds.")
        }, INTERVAL);
    }
}
```